# Swift - "navigationController?.pushViewController" doesn't work

Tags: swift

I have 3 ViewControllers like below.

A: HomeController, 
B: NavController1,
C: NavController2

I set a custom navigation bar in B and C and I use "navigationController?.pushViewController" for the segues From A to B to C.

These are the codes.

Custom navigation bar:

```
class CustomNavBar: UINavigationBar {

    let navBarView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .black

        // Logo
        let logo = UIImageView(image: <image-file>)
        view.addSubview(logo)
        logo.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        logo.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        return view

    }()

    public func setupNavBar() {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            window.addSubview(navBarView)
            navBarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            navBarView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            navBarView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        }
    }

}
```

And in the ViewControllers B and C I put these codes.

```
class NavController1: UIViewController {

    let navBar = CustomNavBar()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white
        navBar.setupNavBar()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        loginHeader.headerBg.isHidden = true
        loginHeader.backButton.isHidden = true
    }

}
```

And for the segues, I used the code below with a UIButton action.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(NavController1, animated: true)
```

It works with the segue from A to B but it doesn't work with B to C.

Can someone point out what the problem is? Thank you!

Comment: It is improper to name "pushViewController" a "segue", because it is not. If you want to use segues, you can bind them all in storyboard, and then trigger required segue by it's id: `performSegue(withIdentifier: , sender: )`

Comment: PS: To avoid confusing yourself and others, avoid naming ordinary ViewControllers like NavController, it will suggest that is is derived from UINavigationController (same for all other types, never named view a Button if it is not a UIButton for example etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I’m not using storyboard. And yes, I’ll name it better for the next time.

Comment: How `NavController1` was created (in both cases)? Did you debugged either `self.navigationController` not nil (it shouldn't to be it you got to controller B by pushing it, but... )

Answer (score 3):

`UINavigationController` is derived from `UIViewController`, which means it has a `navigationController` property. Thing is, this will be nil on the actual `UINavigationController` because it doesn't **have** a navigation controller, it **is** the navigation controller. Because you are using optional chaining, the message is never getting sent because `navigationController` is nil. Try sending the message to `self` instead (given that self is of type `UINavigationController`, **and** the current one).

I.E. `self.pushViewController(NavController1, animated: true)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried self.pushViewController but the error occured "Value of type 'NavController1' has no member 'pushViewController'".